# Gulp image optimization breaks images

Tags: javascript, image, gulp

Using the `gulp-image-optimization` plugin. The plugin outputs, that the images are optimized; however they appear to be broken/empty after the script runs. A snippet of the `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('img', function(cb) {
gulp.src(['public/img/**/*.png', 'public/img/**/*.jpg', 'public/img/**/*.jpeg', 'public/img/**/*.gif'])
    .pipe(imgOptimize({
        optimizationLevel: 5,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/img'))
    .on('end', cb)
    .on('error', cb);
});
```

Can anyone explain to me why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [gulp blacklist](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json), you should use [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin) instead.